# Look up and string operation; fetch a value based on searching a partial string

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 2 sets of data. One set to be filled up by fetching relevant data from a data array.

DATA to be FILLED:

```
Part#1   Part#2

4021006  
3808587  
3870480  
3083410  
3873905  
3890030  
4002065  
3699803  
3930218
```

ARRAY OF DATA:

```
Part#1                      Part#2

4021006;3808587                1  
3808587                        2  
3870480;3083410;4002065        3  
3083410                       34  
3873905                       54  
3890030                       32  
4002065;3930218               65  
3699803                       75  
3930218                       68
```

I need to match Part#1 and find Part#2.

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
Part#1  Part#2

4021006 1  
3808587 1;2  
3870480 3  
3083410 3;4  
3873905 54  
3890030 32  
4002065 3;65  
3699803 75  
3930218 65;68
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: @pnuts 99% of the credit goes to `@slbarts`, he proposed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems too localised to me to be worth explaining all the steps in detail in case of benefit to others, so in outline only:

1. Parse Part#1 into individual 7 character strings (3 separate 
   columns).
2. Create a two column pivot table from these 3 columns and
   Part#2.
3. Copy that pivot table, Paste Special, Values somewhere available (say `G30`), delete rows that display blank in any cell, sort in Part#1 order.
4. Enter
   `=IF(G29=G30=G31,H29&";"&H30&";"&H31,IF(G30=G31,H30&";"&H31,IF(G31<>G32,H31,"")))`
   in `I31` and copy down.
5. Delete rows that display blank and  use result  as array to supply look up values to DATA to be FILLED.

Result is not  EXPECTED OUTPUT because of inconsistency in the question.

Process is (a) make ARRAY OF DATA more manageable (by parsing). (b) 'combine'  columns (with PivotTable). (c) String together Part#2 components (with formula). (d) Preserve  seemingly arbitrary order (by `LOOKUP`).